# Can System.exit() return without terminating the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

In practice of course it is very unlikely to happen, but:
Is there **any** reason for this method call not to terminate the JVM?

Is it possible for example, that an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown immediately after (or while) calling `System.exit(0)` or that a `StackOverflowError` occurs when calling this method, because the stack is just overflowing in that moment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any reason for this method call not to terminate the JVM?

Yes.

[From the docs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-)

> Throws:
>
> SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkExit method doesn't allow exit with the specified status.

Comment: You could also have a shutdown hook that throws an exception.

Comment: @Tunaki - what do you mean? That doesn't affect the behavior of `exit()`

Comment: @bayou.io Instead of throwing an exception, I meant looping forever. If a shutdown hook loop forever, the call to `exit()` won't make the VM exit. But it's unclear what the OP means by "return": the Javadoc tell "This method never returns normally".

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to produce a stack overflow on `System.exit()`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        main(args);  // recursion
    }
    catch (StackOverflowError e1)
    {
        System.out.println("OK.");
    }

    try
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (StackOverflowError e2)
    {
        System.out.println("HA!");
    }
}
```

After `e1` occurs, `println()` and `exit()` still work, as if there are still some space on stack.

Comment: So when a `StackOverflowError` is thrown, there is still enough free space on the stack to call one more method? That would explain, why it still reaches the exit call.

Comment: hmm... my code is probably flawed. What could happen is that, when first `StackOverflowError` occurs, we try `println("OK")`, which fails too with another `StackOverflowError`, which is thrown and caught by the parent caller; the parent caller then executes `println()` and `exit()` with success, because the stack has enough space.